# Different p-values given by corr.test and cor.test with kendall correlations in R

Tags: r, correlation

I wanted to calculate kendalls correlations with corr.test because this function can easily correct for multiple testing for example with bonferroni correction. But corr.test gives me different p-values than cor.test (although kendalls tau is the same).
Strangely when I use a different correlation coefficient as pearson or spearman all values are the same as it should be.
Are corr.test adn cor.test using different test for the p-values with kendall correlations? And which one is better?
Thanks for help!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is difficult to help without examples. Please take a look at these tips on how to produce a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as this post on [creating a great example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Perhaps the following tips on [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be worth a read.

Comment: You may want to edit this question and post it on the Cross Validate, http://stats.stackexchange.com/   That site is more geared towards your statisitics question.